# Improve Parameterized Query Performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I have been tasked to improve the performance of a SQL Server 2008 R2 query (within a stored procedure) shown in the query execution plan link below.

It currently executes in around 7 seconds and needs to complete in 1-2 seconds if possible. Each execution of the slow query is always around 7 seconds. The results of the query trickle through. The tables being queried are large but not billions of rows.

#### Row counts

[image: Row Counts]

Depending on the parameters being passed the results can either be a few hundred rows (which executes sub second) to > 300K rows (this is slow).

I have included the [slow query execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byln-kp3b) and indices that are being utilised by the optimiser. This is the [plan for the quicker execution](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkBWxxTh-) and `STATISTICS IO, TIME`:

[image: AsIs StatsIO_Time]

There are two queries being executed. The first one is not the issue. It's the second one that I need assistance with. Although needed, removing the non SARGable predicate (`AND FT.TripDistance < ( CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,0),FT.TripTime) * 83.33 )`) makes slight difference to the speed

[image: remove non SARG]

Removing the function [FN_GetLocalTime_FromUTC_BasedOnTZId] makes slight difference to the speed, here's the `STATISTICS IO TIME` removing both non SARG where clause and function: Here's the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByPuPSBzf)

[image: remove non SARG and Func]

Here's the output for the unchanged query except for adding a `LOOP JOIN` hint. This is slower.

[image: LoopJoin]

I have noticed that in the slow unchanged query plan, the actual number of rows (300330) for the Index Seek on the `FACT_trip_Statuses` table is close to the final output (299887). However, the actual number of rows (4.87m) on the index seeks on the `xFactTrip_Annex`, `FACT_Trip`, and `FACT_Trip_Attributes` is way out. How do I fix this?  Adding `OPTION RECOMPILE` make little difference

I tried adding trace flag 4199 `DBCC TRACEON (4199, -1);` and retrying with and without `JOIN` hints, didn't help.

#### HASH join hint and TF 4199

[image: HASH join hint and TF4199]

#### LOOP join hint and TF 4199

[image: LOOP join hint and TF4199]

#### No join hints and TF 4199

[image: No JOIN hints and TF4199]

#### Indices

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_FACT_Trip_StartDateUTC_VehicleKey_Includes ON dbo.FACT_Trip
(
    StartDateUTC ASC,
    VehicleKey ASC,
    EndDateUTC ASC
)
INCLUDE (   DriverKey,
    DrivingTime,
    TripDistance,
    TripTime)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_xFactTrip_Annex_StartDateUTC_MonthlyProcessing ON dbo.xFactTrip_Annex
(
    StartDateUTC ASC
)
INCLUDE (   VehicleKey,
            Spd20Count, Spd20Distance,
            Spd30Count, Spd30Distance,
            Spd40Count, Spd40Distance,
            Spd50Count, Spd50Distance,
            Spd60Count, Spd60Distance,
            Spd70Count, Spd70Distance,
            SpdCat1,SpdCat2,SpdCat3,
            TotalIdling,
            PTOTime,
            TripFuel) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FACT_Trip_Attributes_StartDateUTC_VehicleKey_Includes ON dbo.FACT_Trip_Attributes
(
    StartDateUTC ASC,
    VehicleKey ASC,
    EndDateUTC ASC
)
INCLUDE (   Attribute0Distance,
    Attribute1Distance,
    Attribute2Distance,
    Attribute3Distance,
    Attribute4Distance,
    Attribute5Distance,
    Attribute6Distance,
    Attribute7Distance,
    Attribute8Distance,
    Attribute9Distance,
    Attribute10Distance)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_FACT_Trip_Statuses_StartDateUTC_VehicleKey_Includes ON dbo.FACT_Trip_Statuses
(
    VehicleKey ASC,
    StartDateUTC ASC,
    EndDateUTC ASC
)
INCLUDE (   HarshAccelerationCount,
    HarshBrakeCount,
    HarshBumpCount,
    HarshCorneringCount,
    ExcessIdleDuration,
    ExcessIdleCount,
    OverspeedCount)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_StartDateUTC_VehicleKey_IsBP ON dbo.FACT_TripComments
(
    StartDateUTC ASC
)
INCLUDE (   VehicleKey, IsBusinessPrivate)
```

Comment: All of those unions. could you not use WHERE ... OR... OR instead of hitting those tables 4 separate times? Also, any way of getting rid of that function in the cross join? Also, do you *need* that MAXDOP hint to stop it going parallel?

Comment: If I'm reading the plan right, it looks like the `FN_GetLocalTime_FromUTC_BasedOnTZId` function is where the bulk of the time goes. It also looks like the values from that function are only used in the `SELECT` list. Could you post that function? Also: instead of executing in the function, could you perform that date transformation directly in the `SELECT` list itself (the posting of the function may answer this question)?

Comment: Looks like a Leica database. We had an identical problem with that exactly named UDF. We used another method to convert to local time and got better performance.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid   this is not a Leica database. The name of the function being the same is just a coincidence

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Is the function using _procedural_ code to apply a timezone offset to a UTC time? Anyway if you've removed it with little difference it probably doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Probably a clustered index over the #xMobiles temp table can help you in the last Join

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_xMobiles_VehicleKey ON #xMobiles
(
    VehicleKey ASC,
)
```

The best option is to create the index after populating the table.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this query still has faults and I can't test it against your data, but would this produce the same results and run a little faster?

```
WITH cteBusGrps
  AS(
   SELECT
    LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(A.Value AS INT))) 'BusGrpId', BG.BusinessGroupKey
   FROM
    dbo.FN_SplitString_AB (@nvBusGrpIds_csv, ',') A
   CROSS APPLY
    Warehouse.dbo.DIM_BusinessGroup BG
   WHERE
    vn = 1 
   AND
    BG.CtrackNodeID = CAST(A.Value AS INT)
  )
  INSERT INTO #xMobiles
  (
     NodeId
   , VehicleKey
   , VehicleId
   , CostCentreName
   , BusGrpId
   , BusGrpKey
   , AssignStart
   , AssignEnd
   , vGrpId
   , vGrpName
  )
  SELECT 
    V.vNodeId
   ,V.VehicleKey
   ,CAST(V.VehicleId AS NVARCHAR(50))
   ,V.CostCentreName
   ,V.BusGrpId
   ,V.BusinessGroupKey
   ,V.CreateDate
   ,COALESCE(V.DeletedTime,V.DeInstalled_DT,'2100-12-31 23:59:59') 
   ,V.vGrpId
   ,CAST(V.vGrpName AS NVARCHAR(100))
  FROM
   dbo.xED_Mobiles_OCC_ViewTable V
  INNER JOIN
   cteBusGrps      B ON B.BusinessGroupKey = V.BusinessGroupKey
  WHERE
   (
    ( CreateDate <= @dtStartDate_LT AND DeletedTime IS NULL ) 
    OR ( CreateDate <= @dtStartDate_LT AND DeletedTime BETWEEN @dtStartDate_LT AND @dtEndDate_LT )
    OR ( CreateDate BETWEEN @dtStartDate_LT AND @dtEndDate_LT ) 
    OR ( @dtStartDate_LT BETWEEN CreateDate AND COALESCE(V.DeletedTime,V.DeInstalled_DT,'2100-12-31 23:59:59')
  ) 

   SELECT
     M.BusGrpKey
    ,M.VehicleKey
    ,M.AssignStart
    ,M.AssignEnd
    ,FT.StartDateUTC
    ,D.LocalStartDateTime
    ,D.LocalEndDateTime
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(FT.DriverKey,0) < 1 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(FT.DriverKey,0) END 
            'DriverKey'
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(FT.DriverKey,0) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            'UnknownTrips'
    ,FTS.HarshAccelerationCount
    ,FTS.HarshBrakeCount
    ,FTS.HarshBumpCount
    ,FTS.HarshCorneringCount
    ,FTS.ExcessIdleDuration
    ,FTS.ExcessIdleCount
    ,FTS.OverspeedCount
    ,A.Spd20Count
    ,A.Spd20Distance
    ,A.Spd30Count
    ,A.Spd30Distance
    ,A.Spd40Count
    ,A.Spd40Distance
    ,A.Spd50Count
    ,A.Spd50Distance
    ,A.Spd60Count
    ,A.Spd60Distance
    ,A.Spd70Count
    ,A.Spd70Distance
    ,FT.TripDistance
    ,CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,0),FT.TripTime) * 83.33 'Ignore'
    ,FT.DrivingTime
    ,A.TotalIdling
    ,A.PTOTime
    ,FT.TripTime
    ,CAST( A.TripFuel AS DECIMAL(10,3))
            'TripFuel'
    ,CASE 
      WHEN CAST( A.TripFuel AS DECIMAL(10,3)) > 0 
       THEN FT.TripDistance
      ELSE 0
     END      'Tot_TF_DistTravelled'
    ,A.SpdCat1
    ,CAST(A.SpdCat2 AS INT)  'SpdCat2'
    ,CAST(A.SpdCat3 AS INT)  'SpdCat3'
    ,CASE   --EX-660
     WHEN FTA.Attribute0Distance > 0  THEN 0 
     WHEN FTA.Attribute1Distance > 0  THEN 1
     WHEN FTA.Attribute2Distance > 0  THEN 2
     WHEN FTA.Attribute3Distance > 0  THEN 3
     WHEN FTA.Attribute4Distance > 0  THEN 4
     WHEN FTA.Attribute5Distance > 0  THEN 5
     WHEN FTA.Attribute6Distance > 0  THEN 6
     WHEN FTA.Attribute7Distance > 0  THEN 7
     WHEN FTA.Attribute8Distance > 0  THEN 8
     WHEN FTA.Attribute9Distance > 0  THEN 9
     WHEN FTA.Attribute10Distance > 0 THEN 10
     ELSE 0
     END        'AttributeTypeId'
    ,ISNULL( TC.IsBusinessPrivate,0 ) 'BPOverride'
   FROM
    #xMobiles        M
   INNER JOIN
    Warehouse.dbo.FACT_Trip    FT ON FT.VehicleKey = M.VehicleKey
               AND FT.StartDateUTC BETWEEN @dtStartDate_LT AND @dtEndDate_LT
               AND FT.TripDistance < CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,0),FT.TripTime) * 83.33
   INNER JOIN
    dbo.xFactTrip_Annex      A ON A.VehicleKey = FT.VehicleKey
               AND A.StartDateUTC = FT.StartDateUTC
   INNER JOIN
    Warehouse.dbo.FACT_Trip_Statuses FTS ON FTS.VehicleKey = FT.VehicleKey
               AND FTS.StartDateUTC= FT.StartDateUTC
   INNER JOIN 
    Warehouse.dbo.FACT_Trip_Attributes FTA ON FTA.VehicleKey = FT.VehicleKey 
               AND FTA.StartDateUTC= FT.StartDateUTC
   LEFT JOIN
    Warehouse.dbo.FACT_TripComments  TC ON TC.VehicleKey = FT.VehicleKey
               AND TC.StartDateUTC = FT.StartDateUTC
   CROSS APPLY
    dbo.FN_GetLocalTime_FromUTC_BasedOnTZId(FT.StartDateUTC, FT.EndDateUTC, 2) D
   WHERE
   (
    ( FT.StartDateUTC BETWEEN M.AssignStart AND M.AssignEnd )
    OR ( M.AssignStart <= FT.StartDateUTC AND M.AssignEnd BETWEEN FT.StartDateUTC AND FT.EndDateUTC )
   )
```

Comment: the MAXDOP hint is added to prevent the query going parallel. Your recent amendment has slowed the query down a little.  Also, the CROSS APPLy function is required and removing it makes no difference to the speed.